# "I had fallen asleep" vs "I fell asleep"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

Which sentence below is grammatically correct?

1. I didn't answer your questions because **I had fallen asleep** early last night.
2. I didn't answer your questions because **I fell asleep** early last night.

I'm leaning more toward the second sentence since the time was specified, and I don't see why the past perfect is needed.
Please, correct me if I'm wrong, and thanks in advance.

Comment: they're both correct, but mean slightly different things in that they give a clue as to the relative time when it happened.  see "pluperfect tense"

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? how do they mean different things ?

Comment: E.g. "I arrived late, because I had missed the bus" .... in this case the fact that the two events did not happen at the same time is fairly obvious, but the "had" emphasizes that it was even further in the past.   Unnecessary use of this can sound archaic... If not sure, definitely use the ordinary perfect tense  (no "had"). I'm not a writer but I feel like people tend to use the pluperfect more in writing than speech, for a feeling of formality.

Comment: So in my example, both sentences mean that I went to sleep and did not answer the questions, but the difference is that the first sentence emphasizes that the event of going to sleep occurred before answering, and the second just means implies that the both actions just happened in the past and nothing more. is that right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [past simple vs past perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156087/past-simple-vs-past-perfect)

Comment: As far as I understand, yes.

Comment: @PeteW Thank you so much.

Comment: @livresque Not really, but I would like to know if you agree with what I said in the previous comment.

Comment: Without additional context, I might assume that Sentence 1 means that I didn’t see your questions because I had already fallen asleep by the time you sent them.  While 2 could be used when I knew about the questions but fell asleep before I got a chance to answer them.

Comment: Ok thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

"I had fallen asleep" is the (causative + verb) structure. (https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/causative)

It hints for the interlocutor to think about *why* you "had fallen asleep" which happened because of some special reason, or *cause*.

"I fell asleep early last night" does not imply any special hint other than the given "early.".

In essence they're both correct, it just depends on what information (or potential hint) you would like to convey.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: No worries, hope all went well and that... You had not fallen asleep ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following explanations, found in CoGEL 1985 edition § **4.24** p. 195, provides principles of use for the past perfective in comparison with the simple past as well as with the present perfective.

> The past perfective usually has the meaning of 'past-in-the-past', and can be regarded as an anterior version of the present perfective or of the simple past. Consider the following examples:
>
> No wonder Miss Matthews French was excellent—she *had lived* in Paris since childhood. **[1]**
>     When we bought it, the house *had been* empty for several years. **[2]**
> These can be diagrammed as in *Fig* 4.24a, which is a special case of the general perfective diagram *Fig* 4.18:
> [image]
>
> More technically, the past perfective may be said to denote any event or state anterior to a time of orientation in the past. The three meanings of 'state', 'event' or 'habit' (as described in 4.14) can all occur. Whereas [1] and [2]  have illustrated the state meaning, [3] and [4] illustrate 'event' and 'habit' respectively:
>
> The goalkeeper *had injured* his leg, and couldn't play. **[3]**
>     It was foolish to fire McCabe: in two seasons, he *had scored* more goals than any other player. **[4]**
>
> When transposed into the 'past in the past' by means of the past perfective, the contrast between the simple past and the present and the present perfective is neutralized:
>
> My aunt *had lived* in Italy for four years. **[5]**
>     He *had died* in 1920, before his son was born. **[6]**
>
> In [5], the four year period could either be a period leading up to *T2*, or a period which has ceased before *T2*, as would be clear in:
>
> In her youth, my aunt *had lived* in Italy for four years. That's why she spoke Italian so well.
>
> Thus [5] could be a projection further into the past of either [7] or [8]:

> My aunt *lived* in Italy for four years. **[7]**
>     My aunt *had lived* in Italy for four years. **[8]**
>
> But of course, the past perfective does not have to refer to a more remote time than that referred to by the simple past. In some cases, particularly in a clause introduced by *after*, the two constructions can be more or less interchangeable:

> [image]
>
> *After* places the eating (*T2*) after Sandra's return (which we may call *T3*), so the past perfective, which places *T3* before *T2*, is redundant. What difference it does make is a matter of the 'standpoint' of the speaker. In [9] the 'past in the past' time *T3* is identified as being earlier than *T2* by the past perfective; but in [10] it is left to the conjunction *after* to signal this temporal relation.
>
> [image]
>
> Adverbials of time position, when used with the past perfective, can identify either *T2* or *T3*. Placed initially, they often identify *T2*:
>
> *When the police arrived*, the thieves had run away. **[11]**
>
> But in final position, the interpretation whereby the adverbial refers to *T3* is more likely:
>
> The thieves had run away *when the police arrived.* **[12]**
>
> Hence in [11], *when* is likely to be equivalent to *By the time that*…, but in [12] the *when* clause is likely to be an answer to the question: 'When had the thieves run away?'
>
> <sub>**Note**
>
> [**a**] *When* in the sense of 'immediately after' behaves like *after* in sentences [9] and [10]. The following are therefore virtually synonymous:
>
>     I ate my lunch when Sandra *had come* back from her shopping.
>
>     I ate my lunch when Sandra *came* back from her shopping.
>
> [**b**] There is one construction in which the past perfective clearly could not be replaced, as means of referring to past time, by the simple past. This is an indirect speech construction, in which the past perfective indicates backshift (*cf* 14.31) into the more remote past: *I told her the parcel had not arrived.*
>
> [**c**] the past perfective can also be a backshifted equivalent of the present perfective in expressions like *I hadn't noticed*; *I'm leaving – had you heard?* In these cases, a past time of orientation *T2* is implied by the context.
>
> [**d**] As well as past-in-past, the past perfective can be used to indicate hypothetical past (*cf* 4.19, 14.23, 15.35).</sub>

- Sentence 1 : "I didn't answer your questions because I had fallen asleep early last night" or Sentence 2 : "I didn't answer your questions because I fell asleep early last night"

The adverbial "early" does not specify explicitly "T3", but, implicitly, it does: understated, "before the time when I answer question". If the adverbial was not used the second sentence would not appear as clear, but it still could be used.

- I didn't answer your questions because I had fallen asleep  last night.
- I didn't answer your questions because I fell asleep  last night.

([ref. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Diary_of_%C3%89va_Heyman/hGUMAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22because+i+fell+asleep%22&dq=%22because+i+fell+asleep%22&printsec=frontcover)) I don't know what Grandpa answered, because I fell asleep.

([ref. 2](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/i-got-arrested-and-ticketed-under-the-absolute-sob-1948558.html#!)) I got arrested and ticketed under the absolute sobriety law because I fell asleep in my car at a gas station waiting for my ride.

Given the use of "early" in these sentences, it seems that they are interchangeable.

Comment: Thant's the greatest answer I've got so far. Thank you so much!!!