# had vs no had - what is the difference

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

> Under Roth's direction, the press Chamber issued several decrees to domestic news outlets in the weeks leading up to the ceremony.

What if we add a " had " in front of issued ? Will that change the meaning . I know that had is used to distinguish to past incidents in the past. I have seen in several sentences by authors using had + verb mentioning only one incident.

> Under Roth's direction, the press Chamber had issued several decrees to domestic news outlets in the weeks leading up to the ceremony.

Can someone explain the difference , please?

Comment: It's a barely distinguishable change in meaning.

Comment: Thanks.. So authors sometimes use them interchangeably?

Comment: Yes, in this sentence they are more or less interchangeable. You might say that the second is focused on the time frame of the ceremony, while the first is focused on the time frame leading up to the ceremony, but this is a rather subtle difference.

Comment: Thanks so much Peter, It is not easy for a non - native speaker to spot this..thanks.

Comment: Even if you are a native speaker, you might not spot the difference (assuming I'm correct about what the difference is — I don't know that all native speakers would agree with me).

Comment: There is a significant difference in meaning of the two usages, but it doesn't really make much difference in the above context.

Comment: @Hot Licks - would like to learn..can you please the difference in meaning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [past simple vs past perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156087/past-simple-vs-past-perfect)

Comment: If my pain level was below 8 I might oblige you.

Answer (score 1):

When the past perfect is used in its primary role of specifying purely temporal relations,<sup>1</sup> it expresses ***double anteriority.***

<sup><sup>1</sup>Other major uses of the past perfect include [*backshifting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses#English) in reported speech (e.g. *she said she **had had** too many commitments*) and expressing *modal remoteness,* i.e. that something is counterfactual (*I wish I **had accepted** her offer*), or that something is not an open possibility.</sup>

In order to make it more apparent what is going on, I will replace the verb *issue* by the verb *write*. I do this because it will be less confusing if the past tense form of the verb and the past participle form are different, as they are for *write* (*wrote* vs *written*) but not for *issue* (which is a regular verb, so both forms are *issued*).

**Simple past vs. past perfect**

I will be following the discussion in [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), p 140.

When you use the simple past,

[1]  *Under Roth's direction, the press Chamber **wrote** several decrees to domestic news

       outlets in the weeks leading up to the ceremony.*

there are two times being talked about: the ***time of orientation (T<sub>o</sub>),*** which in [1] coincides with the ***time of utterance,*** and the ***time referred to* (*T<sub>r</sub>*)**, which in [1] is the time when the press Chamber wrote the decrees. The meaning of the past tense is to say that *T<sub>r</sub> < T<sub>o</sub>*.

But when you use the past perfect,

[2]  *Under Roth's direction, the press Chamber **had written** several decrees to domestic news

        outlets in the weeks leading up to the ceremony.*

there are **three** distinct times being talked about. Actually, there are even four, but two of them coincide. The temporal structure is as follows:

*T<sub>r</sub>*<sup>2</sup> < T<sub>o</sub>*<sup>2</sup>=T<sub>r</sub>*<sup>1</sup> < T<sub>o</sub><sup>1</sup>.

The most recent time is T<sub>o</sub><sup>1</sup>, the first time of orientation. It is once again identified with the time of utterance.

The time that is the most distant in the past is *T<sub>r</sub>*<sup>2</sup>, identified as the time when the press Chamber wrote the decree.

Finally, there is the **intermediate** time T<sub>o</sub>*<sup>2</sup>=T<sub>r</sub>*<sup>1</sup>. It has two roles. First, it is the time referred to by the past tense *had*; second, it is also the time of orientation for the perfect *written*.

Thus we have a **double anteriority:** the time when the press Chamber wrote the decree is anterior to an intermediate time, which in turn is anterior to the time of utterance.

Given just the isolated sentence [2], it is not clear that we have enough information to deduce what this intermediate time is. What we do know for sure is that there is an intermediate time that the speaker thinks is relevant to the message he or she is trying to convey. Nevertheless, one could argue that the most natural reading is that the intermediate time is the time of the ceremony.<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>Thanks to Peter Shor for pointing this out.</sup>

**An example where it really matters whether we use the simple past or the past perfect**

Consider the following sentences:

[3]  a.  *She left the country before she **wrote** her thesis.*
       b.  *She left the country before she **had written** her thesis.*

The difference in meaning is as follows: [3i] indicates that the leaving preceded the whole of the thesis writing, whereas [3ii] allows, and in fact suggests, that she had already started writing when she left (CGLE, p. 147).

Comment: Isn't the intermediate time *the time of the ceremony?*

Comment: @PeterShor Good point! That's a more likely guess.